# How to make co-ordinate substitution after making a Jacobean transformation?

Tags: definite-integrals, jacobian

A problem asks me to transform the triple integral of f(x,y,z) to f(u,v,w) by given equations[x=au , y=bv , z=cw ], but after transforming can I use the spherical co-ordinates? remember that the triple integral now is in terms of (u,v,w) not (x,y,z).
The original integral is : Evaluate triple integral xyz dx dy dz  over the ellipsoid [ x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 + z^2/c^2 =1]

Comment: Well, that depends. Did you transform by means of spherical coordinates?

Comment: no, I transformed in terms of (u,v,w) because the problem asks to do this, but to solve the integral I need to use the spherical co-ordinates.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the transformation in question.

Comment: The edit is done.

Comment: Then in this case you can

Comment: Thanks a lot man. could you please tell me why.

Comment: After you change variables, you get a new integral in the new variables, which is equal to the integral that you started with. So now you can just forget the original integral, and compute the new integral in whatever way you please (including, for example, using spherical coordinates).